# Define an interval between 2 numbers in Android

Tags: android, math, numbers, int, intervals

I am working with numbers, I get an int from shared preferences, I do some maths and then 
I want to do something IF the result is situated between 2 numbers.

```
SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("shared", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    int A = settings.getInt("A", 1);
    int B = settings.getInt("B", 1);


    operation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.imc );
    operation.setText(A*B);
    String operation;



    if (SOMETHING HERE!) {  // is situated between 1 and 20

        something

    }
```

What should I do?
Any suggestin will be apreciated.

Comment: something depends on what the range is.. ! if it is random, then switch cases, round off etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a simple logic dude.Do the following,

```
if(A>1 && A<20)
{
//Do what ever you want.
}
```